# Including External jar file in cordova plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, jar, cordova-plugins

I add an external .jar file into my Cordova custom plugin but when I was creating the Ionic build its occur error package does not exist but it is imported into my plugin.

Comment: How you imported it? Show you plugin.xml code.

Comment: Here is my plugin.xml                                                                                                             <source-file src="src/android/libs/mPaySdk_sandbox_2.0.8_23102019.jar" target-dir="libs" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the awnser in your comment.
You need to do it that way:

`<lib-file src="src/android/libs/mPaySdk_sandbox_2.0.8_23102019.jar" arch="device"/>`

Comment: Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\bluetoothpluginwrapper\BluetoothPluginWrapper\BluetoothPluginWrapper.java:17: error: package com.pnsol.sdk.auth does not exist
import com.pnsol.sdk.auth.AccountValidator; Same error occuring..

Comment: Did you removed your plugin and added it to the project after the change of plugin.xml?

Comment: Yes, firstly I removed it then added it again.

Comment: Check in Myapp\platforms\android\app\libs if your jar is there. If not. You have problem with the path in src="src/android/libs/mPaySdk_sandbox_2.0.8_23102019.jar".

Comment: Yes it is available in my  Myapp\platforms\android\app\libs\mPaySdk_sandbox_2.0.8_23102019.jar

Comment: If so i think you have some other problem in java code. Maybe the name of the package is not the same in all java files.

Comment: Yes, you are right there was a mismatch of the path. Thank you.